# How do I separate keywords for 2 different users?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-preferences

I have couple of different users on my app. There are certain keywords associated with these users based on their selections and I want to make them such that, user1's kselected keywords are not  displayed for user 2 when he logs on the same device.
Here's the basic code :

```
Boolean firstuserlogin= Sharedpreferences.getinstance().firstlogin;
Boolean sameuserlogin = !Sharedpreferences.getinstance().differentuser;
Boolean differentuserlogin = Sharedpreferences.getinstance().differentuser;

if(firstuserlogin && differentuserlogin) {
//Please note: firsttime user is also considered a new/different user 
m_keyword = Sharedpreferences.getinstance().getkeyword1();
}else if(sameuserlogin){
m_keyword = Sharedpreferences.getinstance().getkeyword1();
}else if(differentuser){
m_keyword = Sharedpreferences.getinstance().getkeyword2();
}else{
m_keyword = Sharedpreferences.getinstance().getkeyword1();
}
```

The issue is I am not able to get it to work as expected.Theoretically: Say a user 1 logs in ,he's considered first user and at the same time a new/different user, until he logs out.His keyword settings which he selects during his session are saved as expected. Now, Say he logs out and logs in again , he should be able to see his keyword settings and be considered as the "sameuser" since he logged in before, unless some other user with a different id logs in on the same device, in which case, it should show all new default keyword(which is lets say keyword2 in this case ) and should not show the previous users selections.Currently based on the above logic I implemented it seems to go haywire, sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesnt recognize the user as a different user, but same user AND VICE VERSA. is there a better and compact way I can restrict and implement this logic?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you insist on using shared preferences, you can use a unique key(email,username,userId anything) and merge it with the keyword and save to share preferences. You will need a special character to seperate the unique key and keyword (somekind of key-value pair)

for example if we use id as uniqkey and ## as token character. keywordA for the keyword you should save as "userid1##keywordA) and read it back from preferences. After you get it. You should split it via ##.

But for such operations shared preferences is not the best place, you should use a database since you have multiple users. Android supports sqlite database built in. You can see a [tutorial here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

Good luck

Comment: I was also thinking maybe I can add a variable that makes sure the firsttimeuser becomes the same user? and the different user after that becomes the other user, any idea on how to go about that?

Comment: With a seperator and user identifier, you will be able to recognize who the user is. Lets say for user 1 nickname is nickname1, seperator ## ( a combination that is unlikely be used in nickname that can be anything) and keyword is carSelection. So when user 1 selects car mercedes. You record it as 

editor.putString("nickname1##carSelection", "mercedes");

When reading it, you can read it  with
getSharedPreferences(context).getString("nickname1##carSelection",null); 
This code will return you value mercedes or null if does not exist. (Instead of null you can return a default value)

Comment: I also highly recommend you to use sqlite database, but its your call.